# Как построить API. Front vs Back

Tags: rest, архитектура, теория

Вопрос теоретический. При начале разработки нового продукта (этап MVP) у которого бэк на Java (микросервисы), front на Angularб над фронтом и бэком работают разные команды, которые начали практически одновременно, кто определяет и назначает API? Имеется в виду адреса ресурсов/сервисов/методов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос состоит не в том "кто назначает/придумывает API" а в том: "для каких целей необходимо создать API".

Если клиент "толстый" (т.е. в нём много бизнес-логики) а бэк - тупо как облачная база данных, то API должна ему соответствовать: API более низкоуровневый (создать/добавить/изменить/удалить и т.д.)

Если клиент "тонкий" (в основном для отображения информации) а бэк обрабатывает бизнес-логику, то API должен быть ориентирован на удобную выдачу информации.